# Cloud Functions & Firestore: Iterate over document.data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The database structure looks like this:

```
User {id}
    Settings (Collection)
        device_uids(document)
            {device_uid_1}: Boolean
            (...)
            {device_uid_n}: Boolean
```

I want to get the document and access all of the device_uids within that document.
I tried like this, however the console logs, that `forEach` is not definded:

```
const settings_ref = admin.firestore().collection('User').doc(uid).collection('Settings').doc('device_uids');
    settings_ref.get()
    .then(snap =>{
        let uids = snap.data();


        uids.array.forEach(element => {
            let device = element.key;
            if(device != device_uid){
               //GO ON
            }
        });

    })
```

How can I access the values individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a field called `array` in your document, so `uids.array` will always be undefined.   If you just want to iterate all the properties of the document, it's just like iterating all the properties of a plain old JavaScript object:

```
const data = snap.data();
for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];
    // now key and value are the property name and value
}
```